# Multi-producer single-consumer executor service design

Tags: java, queue, threadpool, executorservice

I have a `java.util.BlockingQueue` which is full of POJOs which need to be serviced by an `ExecutorService`. This queue must be serviced by a single thread, but will be pushed to from multiple threads at once.

In the past, I've written my solution to look a bit like this, but I really despise it:

```
executorService.execute(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                POJO job = blockingQueue.take();
                servicePOJO(job);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a better way of writing this, or is this the optimal way of doing it? The reason I don't like doing it is because if I need to add multiple consumers, I need to run the above in a loop with the size of the actual thread pool.

Comment: Why aren't you simply using a single thread executor?

Comment: It's not clear what the point is of the `ExecutorService` here, apart from making it seem like you're not creating a thread dedicated to servicing this queue. You certainly are *stealing* a thread to do so, and it's not in keeping with the expected usage of an `ExecutorService`. Also, you're swallowing of `InterruptedException` here, when you should propagate the interruption by calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the ExecutorService with a task per object.

```
public <POJO> void asyncServicePOJO(final POJO pojo) {
    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            servicePOJO(pojo);
        }
    });
}
```

There is no need for an extra queue.